# Passing Objects as Argument to GraphQL Mutation (graphql-request)

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql, graphql-mutation

I have a very basic graphql mutation in the frontend that I send to my backend. I am using [this code](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request#graphql-mutations) on the by `graphql-request` as a guide.

With primitives it works:

```
const mutation = gql`
    mutation EditArticle($id: ID!, $title: String) {
      editArticle(id: $id, title: $title) {
        id
      }
    }
  `
```

Now I'd like to also be able to mutate some meta data about the article, stored in a `meta` object inside the article:

```
...,
title: "Hello World",
meta: {
 author: "John",
 age: 32,
 ...
}
```

So my question is: *How do I pass over non-primitive object types as arguments to mutations when making the request from the frontend, using [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request)?*

I tried something like this already:

```
const Meta = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Meta",
    fields: () => ({
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      name: { type: GraphQLString },
      age ....
    }),
  })
   
const mutation = gql`
    mutation EditArticle($id: ID!, $title: String, $meta: Meta) { //??? I don't seem to get what goes here? 
      editArticle(id: $id, title: $title, meta: $meta) {
        id
      }
    }
  `
```

I also tried it with `GraphQLObjectType`, but I think I am going wrong here (since this is the frontend).

PS: I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603182/passing-complex-arguments-to-graphql-mutations), but I didn't understand / believe the solution there might be incomplete.

Comment: Look in your schema what the types of the `editArticle` arguments are. Most likely it should be something like `MetaInput`. It needs to be an `input` type, not an output one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I understand now. So the MetaInput type is something I define on the server, but on the client I can just write that it's of the type `MetaInput` and there's no need to define this again on the client, as I understand now?

Comment: Yes, if you're using `express-graphql`, though of course the server side is implementation dependent (and you don't necessarily need to construct a `new GraphQLInputObjectType` yourself - you might just parse a schema definition or something). But on the frontend, where you're defining the query, you'd just refer to it by name, you don't have to do anything extra.

Comment: Ok, I think this was the bit that had me confused!! Thank you (so!) much. If you just write that as an answer, I would definitely accept that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the input object type in your serverside schema, as something like

```
input MetaInput {
  name: String
  author: String
  release: Date
}
```

and use it in the `editArticle` definition

```
extend type Mutation {
  editArticle(id: ID!, title: String, meta: MetaInput): Article
}
```

Then you can also refer to the `MetaInput` type in the clientside definition of your `mutation EditArticle`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful!